# Rubyのコードがターミナルで実行できない

Tags: ruby

YouTubeでRubyの動画を見てその通り動かして学習してみようとしました。Macbookを使用。VS codeにてコードを入力。表示のターミナルにて実行。

puts "Good morning"

Puts "Good afternoon"

この２行を実行しましたが結果反映されていません。ターミナルに反映されないのは何かを探るにはどこを見ると良いでしょうか？
Rubyを使うのは本日が初めてです。どうかご教授いただけると幸いです。

ちなみにRuby Extension packはインストール済みです。

Comment: もう少し具体的に質問を編集追記してください。例えば、どのようなソースを記述して、ターミナルではどのようなコマンドを実行して、ターミナル上にはどのようなエラーメッセージが表示されるのか、等です

Comment: `puts "Good morning"` と入力した時に何も表示されませんか？ それとも何かエラーメッセージが表示されますか？ エラーメッセージが出てるのであれば、質問に追記してください。

Comment: Macbook ならターミナル開いて ruby -v とタイプしてみてください。
ruby が入っているならバージョン番号が表示されるはずです。

VS code で `puts "Good morning"` と書いてファイルに保存してください。
(例えば `/tmp/hoge.rb` というファイルにします)
そしてターミナルから `ruby /tmp/hoge.rb` とタイプし結果が表示されたらうまくいっています。